# Xcode iOS Swift: Automatically generate protocol function overrides

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift, protocols

Is there any way to have Xcode automatically generate protocol functions for you so your class conforms to your protocol? For example:

My protocol:

```
protocol ProtocolDownloadFile {
    func fileReturned(file: NSDictionary, metaData: String)
    func connectionError(connectionError: ConnectionError)
}
```

If I implement this class:

```
class NetworkController: NSObject {

}
```

and specify the protocol:

```
class NetworkController: NSObject, ProtocolDownloadFile {

}
```

I want my class to automatically insert the functions for me like:

```
class NetworkController: NSObject, ProtocolDownloadFile {
    //I want these to be automatically generated 
    func fileReturned(file: NSDictionary, metaData: String) {
    }
    func connectionError(connectionError: ConnectionError) {        
    }
}
```

Can Xcode do this for me? I can see that if I have a Protocol with many functions, it will take an phenominal amount of time to write them all out. Its the same functionality I want as in Eclipse implementing an interface in Java.

Comment: AppCode will do it for obj c. Once they fully support swift, it'll probably work for that as well.

Comment: Why not just copy & paste it from the header?

Comment: Do you find an answer ? I am using Swift 2